# Displaying the image in the background when scrolling text

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I create an effect that is to constantly display the image while scrolling text. I have a question how to make it work the same way, instead of position: sticky, posititon: fixed, so that this effect works on ie.

```js
var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky-container');
var img = document.querySelector('.sticky-item');
window.addEventListener('scroll',setSticky);        
function setSticky(){
  var top = sticky.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset;
  if(top <= 0){
    sticky.classList.add('sticky');
  }
  if(top.toString().replace('-','') >= sticky.offsetHeight || top >= 0){
    sticky.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 120vh 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 80px 0;
}
.sticky-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xs/a/images/overview/camera_hero_large.jpg) center / cover no-repeat;
}
.sticky-container.sticky .sticky-item{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-container">
  <figure class="sticky-item"></figure>
  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, magni suscipit modi enim assumenda optio tenetur recusandae sed nobis veritatis!</p>
  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, at.</p>
  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit laudantium, esse omnis neque, minima voluptatibus repellendus amet, quod odio architecto veniam fuga inventore adipisci! Delectus fugit quisquam ad, ab facilis at saepe? Soluta delectus consequuntur fuga ipsa quasi dolorem officiis?</p>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dolorum ipsum distinctio ut excepturi facilis laborum, nihil in aliquid assumenda necessitatibus quaerat recusandae. Nobis, dolore? Hic itaque ipsa inventore illo tempora similique perspiciatis architecto rem, nulla dicta error saepe earum ut atque aut aspernatur deserunt doloribus odit ea, a reprehenderit?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need any scripts at all - just use `background-position: fixed;`.

Comment: Looks different from what I have now.

Comment: I want that look the same.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
<div class="sticky-container">

  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, magni suscipit modi enim assumenda optio tenetur recusandae sed nobis veritatis!</p>
  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, at.</p>
  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit laudantium, esse omnis neque, minima voluptatibus repellendus amet, quod odio architecto veniam fuga inventore adipisci! Delectus fugit quisquam ad, ab facilis at saepe? Soluta delectus consequuntur fuga ipsa quasi dolorem officiis?</p>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dolorum ipsum distinctio ut excepturi facilis laborum, nihil in aliquid assumenda necessitatibus quaerat recusandae. Nobis, dolore? Hic itaque ipsa inventore illo tempora similique perspiciatis architecto rem, nulla dicta error saepe earum ut atque aut aspernatur deserunt doloribus odit ea, a reprehenderit?</p>

  </div>


  .sticky-item {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
  }
```

Dai is correct, you do not need to use a script to achieve this effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/tractionworks/h3r5uvqm/8/

Comment: This effect doesn't look the same, There's no text on the picture.

Comment: Still doesn't look the same.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve? Do you want the image to be flush with the top. Please advise.

Comment: You have an example in the question, you can check what the code does ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use the `position:sticky` feature I doubt this works on IE without a big effort and actually using JS. But with [1.4% global usage](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) I doubt this is worth your time.

However if you are fine with the coverage of `sticky`, I would entirely skip using JS and solve it via CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 120vh 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 80px 0;
}
.sticky-item {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xs/a/images/overview/camera_hero_large.jpg) center / cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-item"></div>
<div class="sticky-container">
  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, magni suscipit modi enim assumenda optio tenetur recusandae sed nobis veritatis!</p>
  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, at.</p>
  <p class="anim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit laudantium, esse omnis neque, minima voluptatibus repellendus amet, quod odio architecto veniam fuga inventore adipisci! Delectus fugit quisquam ad, ab facilis at saepe? Soluta delectus consequuntur fuga ipsa quasi dolorem officiis?</p>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dolorum ipsum distinctio ut excepturi facilis laborum, nihil in aliquid assumenda necessitatibus quaerat recusandae. Nobis, dolore? Hic itaque ipsa inventore illo tempora similique perspiciatis architecto rem, nulla dicta error saepe earum ut atque aut aspernatur deserunt doloribus odit ea, a reprehenderit?</p>
</div>
```